# PHP Script exits automatically when running large MySQL stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, cron

I have a PHP script that runs multiple MySQL procedures. One Procedure takes more time to run and takes high CPU utilization. While running the procedure the PHP script exits automatically. What is the issue here and how can solve it?

I set all waiting time and run time to maximum already.

Comment: Have you looked in your php error log for any clues?

Comment: i think there is some thing related to your RAM or CPU utilization monitor you memory and cpu while cron job is running. and if it is exceeding its limits than past you queries here so any one can helps you to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys.

Comment: Hi Qasim as you suggested the cpu utilization exceeds over 90% while the first stored procedure runs.Before it finished php exits.

Comment: there is no error logged in error log

Answer (score 0):

Make sure error reporting is set, maximum time, and increase memory available to PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit','600M');
ini_set('max_execution_time',9999999);
```

Comment: Can you check for how much time the script runs before it exits?

Comment: it is running for around 5 mins once it reaches cpu percentage around 90 it quits i think